# Constructing ODEs from a Hamiltonian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, hamilton-equations

I'm reading this [book](https://books.google.com.sa/books?id=cPTxCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ar&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and came across this specific Hamiltonian in equation (5.2). My question is how to construct the corresponding system of ODEs explicitly. I am familiar with doing so in a simple 2D system where for instance $x'(t) = \partial H/\partial y$ and $y'(t) = -\partial H/\partial x$, but I get confused with a larger system like (5.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general system of equations is, in vector notation ($q,p \in \mathbb{R}^N$)
$$\begin{cases}
q'=\nabla_p H \\
p'=-\nabla_q H
\end{cases}
$$
which means
$$\begin{cases}
q_i'=\partial H / \partial p_i \\
p_i'=-\partial H / \partial q_i
\end{cases}
$$
for every $i=1,..,N$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was talking about the system after the change of variable (i.e. (2.5)). What exactly would change then?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Just differentiate the Hamiltonian with respect to the new variables.

Comment: However, this does not work for a generic change of variables, but just with a canonical one. Look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thanks